# image submit button for form with action=#

Tags: image, forms, button

i have a form that works well and i wanted to change the looks of my submit button,
i tried this code to change my button into image

```
    <input src="image.png" name="doRegister" type="image" value="Register">
```

but i got an error,
submit button doesn't do what it suppose to, its like it ignores everything

here's my code when the button is click

```
       if($_POST['doRegister'] == 'Register') 
           { 
          some manipulation
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
[Input image tag - webdesign.about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-image-tag.htm)

> INPUT Image Special Notes:
>
> When you use the input type="image" tag, you are telling the browser
>   to submit the x and y coordinates where the image was clicked. This
>   allows you to add image map type functionality to your forms.